# Testing Javascript Class Properties with React and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I currently have a React class that has some class properties.

```
class Foo extends React.component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if (this.props.x) {
      this.y = ...
      this.z = ...
    }
  }
}
```

How can I test for the existence of these class properties with Enzyme with React?

Comment: you want to test if `y` and `z` exist?

Comment: yeah just in case there are changes in the future, these two properties need to exist for other methods